# How can i achieve img coming out from border. email templates?

Tags: html, css, html-email

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyNOF.jpg

I need banner with height 100px. and img inside it with height 120px. So  the picture comeee out my banner for 20px;
Its for emails.
Also i need text column right before picture, so that text in column with background f4f4f4

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <img src="" style="margin-top:-20px;" />
      </td>
      <td>
        banner text here
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried in code till now?
Can you please share that?

Comment: @sanjay edited my question, added code

Comment: So you are wanting the image to extend outside of the table?

Comment: @Paige Meinke yes I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this two ways, one involved slicing the image into two and the other is using two more tables. I have added the code below for you to decide which one you want to go with.

Option 1:
This option has the image as one piece sitting in an outer table with 3 columns. The outer two columns have a table with white background to cater for the heads/hats popping out of the grey area. I have set the table width at 100% to show it will look.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td valign="top" bgcolor="#f4f4f4">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="height: 23px;" height="23"></td>
   </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
  <td width="171" valign="top"><img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/sdk1hh.jpg" width="171" height="178" style="display: block;"></td>
  <td valign="top" bgcolor="#f4f4f4">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="height: 23px;" height="23"></td>
   </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Option 2
For this option, you will need to slice the top part of the image (with white background) and place both the images in one table with two rows. Both images are centered and I have set the table width at 100% to show it will look.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff"><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/lz7f6.png" style="display: block;">
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#f4f4f4"><img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/4qo1mu.png" style="display: block;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The final outcome for both codes should look like this:

[image: Final Outcome]

Let me know which option best suits you.

** **UPDATE** **

Your question asked if you can have option 1 with image to the left and text on the right, here is the example:

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td width="171" valign="top" style="padding-left:20px;"><img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/sdk1hh.jpg" width="171" height="178" style="display: block;"></td>
  <td valign="top" bgcolor="#f4f4f4">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="height: 23px;" height="23"></td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
      <td style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#000000; padding:5px 10px;">This is some text for your email</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: first option is nice. Thank you. Can i achieve that picture will be at left side?

Comment: You can remove the left column from the 3 column table and things should align by itself

Comment: I have added an update to the answer with what you have just asked.

Comment: @ Syfer ok, my bad incorrect question. What code should i have that i can rule padding left for picture and add some more text or something in table right from picture?

Comment: On the right column (with the white bar) add another row under that **same** table and place your text in.

Comment: how can i achieve padding left side for picture?

Comment: Give the padding left to the image. It will shift it right.

Comment: If my answer is right please accept it as an accepted answer (a plus one would be nice as well :-) )

Comment: OK, I will. Can you please post the code with table for text? Can't do it. Also padding for picture doesnt work

Comment: My answer was based on the original question you had asked. Maybe edit your question above. Also padding-left is to be placed on the td not the image itself. \

Comment: The text should be right after picture at column with background f4f4f4

Comment: Edit your original question to add these in please? Or my answer will not make sense to anyone reading it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I cant give you reputation because i dont have 15 rep. If i can give something for you please PM me how.

Comment: Oh no! We are here to help. If i had to do it for anything else i would have given you my email to contact me with. IF this has solved your problem you can accept the answer and if you need my help in future look for syfer_darknight on twitter and message me ;-)

Comment: hi again, if this is the right answer please accept it. cheers

Comment: There is a tick under the voting? Click on it to accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I added colors so you could see that it was outside the table. I gave the image a height of 120px, width of auto. Made the td's have a max-height of 100px; And I left your -20px margin on the image.

```html
<body style="background-color:pink">
<table style="background-color:orange;">
   <tr>
      <td style="max-height:100px; overflow-y:initial;">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZESO4DT.png" style="margin-top:-20px; height:120px; width:auto;" />
      </td>
      <td style="max-height:100px;overflow-y:initial;">
        banner text here
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: add overflow-y:initial to the td's and then yeah it will. Worked on my test.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke, which email client did you test this on? Outlook and a few email clients don't support overflow. I know iOS does as it renders emails using webkit.

Comment: How did u test it?

Comment: If you are asking me, I have been doing emails for roughly 8 years now and i know overflow doesn't work in outlook 2007+

Comment: @Syfer I'm currently writing a laravel application and tested sending it through there to my yahoo/gmail email. But I don't use outlook, so maybe that's why it worked.

Comment: If you are into building emails, there is a list of enemy's on campaign monitors sure that will be helpful ;-)